# File upload Change file name

Tags: php, file-upload, rename

I found an appropriate script that lets me upload multiple image files to the server. What i am trying to do is just change the name of the files and have no idea how i would do it using this code. Could someone please tell me what i need to do? Thanks

```
<?php
    /*
     *
     * @ Multiple File upload script.
     *
     * @ Can do any number of file uploads
     * @ Just set the variables below and away you go
     *
     * @ Author: Kevin Waterson
     *
     * @copywrite 2008 PHPRO.ORG
     *
     */

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    /*** the upload directory ***/
    $upload_dir= './uploads';

    /*** numver of files to upload ***/
    $num_uploads = 1;

    /*** maximum filesize allowed in bytes ***/
    $max_file_size  = 99951200;

    /*** the maximum filesize from php.ini ***/
    $ini_max = str_replace('M', '', ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));
    $upload_max = $ini_max * 9991024;

    /*** a message for users ***/
    $msg = 'Please select files for uploading';

    /*** an array to hold messages ***/
    $messages = array();

    /*** check if a file has been submitted ***/
    if(isset($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']))
    {
        /** loop through the array of files ***/
        for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);$i++)
        {
            // check if there is a file in the array
            if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i]))
            {
                $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
            }
            /*** check if the file is less then the max php.ini size ***/
            elseif($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > $upload_max)
            {
                $messages[] = "File size exceeds $upload_max php.ini limit";
            }
            // check the file is less than the maximum file size
            elseif($_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i] > $max_file_size)
            {
                $messages[] = "File size exceeds $max_file_size limit";
            }
            else
            {

                // copy the file to the specified dir 
                if(@copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_dir.'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]))
                {
                    /*** give praise and thanks to the php gods ***/

                    $messages[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i].' uploaded';
                }
                else
                {
                    /*** an error message ***/
                    $messages[] = 'Uploading '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i].' Failed';
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
if(@copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_dir.'/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i]))
```

For

```
if(@copy($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i],$upload_dir.'/'.'NAME OF YOUR FILE']))
```